# Bluetooth PAN Connect Android 11

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

My application is connecting to radio via Bluetooth as a PAN device. With new android 11 update this code does not work

```
String sClassName = "android.bluetooth.BluetoothPan";
final Class<?> classLocalBluetoothProfileManager = Class.forName(sClassName);
Constructor<?> ctor = classLocalBluetoothProfileManager.getDeclaredConstructor(Context.class, BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener.class);
ctor.setAccessible(true);
Object instance = ctor.newInstance(getApplicationContext(), new BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener() {     
@Override
public void onServiceConnected(int profile, BluetoothProfile proxy) {
    Method connectMethod = null;
    try {
            connectMethod = proxy.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("connect", BluetoothDevice.class);
            if (((Boolean) connectMethod.invoke(proxy, device))) {
                            System.out.println(">>> ConnectPAN ->true");
                        } else {
                            System.out.println(">>> ConnectPAN ->false");
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println(">>> ConnectPAN ->ex " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                    BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().closeProfileProxy(PAN, proxy);

     // some stuff with connect events
```

On 11 android I get null reference in try method, so may be this api is hidden starting from 11 android.

EDIT:
Actually i found the exception, it is

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Need BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED 
permission: Neither user 10282 nor current process has 
android.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED
```

So, google just hided the API it seems, so how can i connec with PAN to my radio?

So i opened docs and tried to connect with Bluetooth socket:

The idea is described [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth#ConnectingDevices). I dont think i need to rewrite this sample code, but what i've tried:

1. connect with
   "00000000-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb" - default UUID
2. connect with custom uuids
   00001116 and 00001112
   with default and 1116 ID socket does not open with error

   ```
   unable to connect read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1
   ```

when I use 1112 uuid the connection is establishing, but there is no PAN connect, so I don't get IP from device and "Internet access" checkbox in bluetooth device in settings is unchecked.

All these UUID is checked with secure, unsecure and via reflect method.

Also i tried creating socket with reflect and choosing channel, tried all 30 channels, sometimes connect was established but no PAN as well.

```
 socket =(BluetoothSocket) device.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[] {int.class}).invoke(device,1);
```

3. I checked all SO questions and I think the whole internet, but still there is no another solutions. What can be done to try?

EDIT 2:

When i check internet access in bluetooth settings in my device, it connects fine and i can use my application, but i cant connect programmaticly or even havent found how to set this checkbox or pop up this window for user

Comment: Related info: https://source.android.com/devices/architecture/modular-system/tethering#module-format

Comment: @MorrisonChang I changed line with class to

        `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
   sClassName = "android.tethering.BluetoothPan";
  }
  else {
   sClassName = "android.bluetooth.BluetoothPan";
  }`


but still get exception

Comment: also does not work
`android.tethering.bluetooth.BluetoothPan`
there is no such class
`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`

Comment: To my understanding: Bluetooth PAN is optional, the code appears to been moved to an APK (closed source), and based on these AOSP issues: [Bluetooth Tethering Reverts to Off in Android 10](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/155370774) and [Android 11-Bluetooth tethering network sharing failed occasionally.](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/174941071) that ownership of the feature (Google or manufacturer) is in question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this api is in the greylist for Android 11.

But what I see in Android 11 sources :
In the PanService (Bluetooth app) the connect method calls getConnectionState which is ... blacklisted.
So at the end this method should be considered as blacklisted.

Comment: Yes, I investigated this, but I couldn't establish bluetooth PAN connection using other methods, that is my question